# xslt create for each based on fields

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below requirement. The input file will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyResponse>
   <resultStructure>
      <toProcess>true</toProcess>
      <records>
         <Id>ABCD</Id>
         <Name>Walmart|Reebok</Name>
         <City>Kuala Lumpur</City>
     <ResponseType>Radio Button</ResponseType>
      </records>
      <records>
         <Id>1234</Id>
         <Name>Tesco|ASDA|Amazon</Name>
         <City>London</City>
         <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
      <ResponseType>Picklist</ResponseType>
      </records>
      <records>
         <Id>ABCD</Id>
         <Name>ASDA</Name>
         <City>Birmingham</City>
         <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
    <ResponseType>Text</ResponseType>
      </records>
   </resultStructure>
</MyResponse>
```

When the value of field ResponseType is either Picklist or Radio Button, the value of field Name should be spilt into one dataProcessed type for each value separated by pipe as:
Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Id</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>ABCD</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>1</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>Walmart</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
    <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>2</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>Reebok</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>City</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>Kuala Lumpur</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Id</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>1234</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>1</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>Tesco</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
    <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>2</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>ASDA</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
    <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>3</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>Amazon</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>City</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>London</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Country</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>United Kingdom</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Id</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>XYZ</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Name</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>ASDA</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>City</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>London</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Country</FieldName>
         <FieldValue>United Kingdom</FieldValue>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
</result>
```

Here is the code that I am trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/MyResponse">

<result>
<xsl:if test="resultStructure/toProcess = 'true'">

          <xsl:for-each select="resultStructure/records">
            <records>
                  <xsl:for-each select="./*">


<dataProcessed>


                 <name>
             <xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
             </name>
                <valstr>
                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                </valstr>


 </dataProcessed>


                </xsl:for-each>
                </records>
               </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:if> 
</result>


   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to break the element Name into different parts using the condition if ResponseType is either 'Radio Button' or 'Picklist'.If I add the test condition as , how should I modify the code.Please guide me.

Comment: What have you tried and achieved so far and where does your actual problem start?

Comment: "I need XSLT code" is not a question.

Comment: Apologies for directly asking for the code. I have tried many things in bits and pieces but none of the codes is completely solving the problem.

Comment: @Tpi Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: That is a significantly different question - do a search for *tokeniize*.

Comment: Ok, using tokenize I can break the string, but not sure how to construct the if else logic for populating the dataProcessed segment based on this. Also note that in case if the value of <ResponseType> matches the criteria, the segment containing the original name is removed & is replaced by new segments with one name each. Is this possible using XSLT?